# Java adding value to existing value (int)

Tags: java, int, double, addition

So I'm making this lottery game for practice and I'm almost done (I'm a beginner of java, needed alot of help to get this far). The final thing that I need before it's finished is to find a way for my "bank" to not reset each time the game is played.

The game is a lottery, each time you press a button you win or lose and that amount is supposed to be added or subtracted to or from your bank. But instead it simply replaces what is already in the bank. This is the code for the entire game and here is also a picture of what it looks like:

http://i.gyazo.com/6390524f6cdc7ddfdacb033499de4094.png

TheLottery.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class TheLottery extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
 **author Samy
 */

JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Lottery");
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
JButton tip = new JButton("Tip");
JButton play = new JButton("Play");
JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
JLabel label = new JLabel();
JLabel tableLabel = new JLabel();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public void TheLottery() {

    southPanel.add(tableLabel);
    northPanel.add(tip);
    northPanel.add(play);
    northPanel.add(exit);
    centerPanel.add(label);
    mainPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainPanel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    tableLabel.setText("<html><center><font size=5 color='white'>The Realistic     Lottery<br><br></font><font size=4 color='white'>Ticket Price: $25<br><br></font><font color='white'>300,000 to 1,000,000 - Loss<br>200,000 to 300,000 - $25<br>30,000 to 200,000 - $50<br>30,000 to 10,000 - $100<br>10,000 to 5,000 - $500<br>1000 to 5,000 - $1,000<br>100 to 1000 - $10,000<br>10 to 100 - $50,000<br>10 to 1 - $250,000<br> Less than 1 - $1,000,000</font><center></html>");

    int width = 720;
    int height = width/16*9;

    frame.setSize(width,height);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.add(mainPanel);

    southPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x222222));
    centerPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x222222));
    northPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x222222));
    mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0x222222));
    mainPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(new Color(0xAAAAAA),new Color(0x666666)));



    play.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);

    tip.setToolTipText("If you win big early, stop and never come back!");
    play.setToolTipText("Click me to play the lottery!");
    exit.setToolTipText("Click me to exit.");

    frame.setVisible(true);

}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object action = e.getSource();

    int bank = 0;
    String win = null;
    double lotteryChance = Math.random()*1000000;

    if(action == play) {

        if (lotteryChance > 300000) {
            win = ("You lost! Better luck next time!");
            bank -= 25;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 300000 && lotteryChance > 200000) {
            win = ("You've won $25!");
            bank += 25;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 200000 && lotteryChance > 30000) {
            win = ("You've won $50!");
            bank += 50;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 30000 && lotteryChance > 10000) {
            win = ("You've won $100!");
            bank += 100;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 10000 && lotteryChance > 5000) {
            win = ("You've won $500!");
            bank += 500;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 5000 && lotteryChance > 1000) {
            win = ("You've won $1,000!");
            bank += 1000;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 1000 && lotteryChance > 100) {
            win = ("You've won $10,000!");
            bank += 10000;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 100 && lotteryChance > 10) {
            win = ("You've won $50,000!");
            bank += 50000;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 10 && lotteryChance > 1) {
            win = ("You've won $250,000!");
            bank += 250000;
        } else if (lotteryChance < 1 && lotteryChance > 0) {
            win = ("YOU'VE WON THE JACKPOT OF $1,000,000!");
            bank += 1000000;
        } else {
            win = ("Something went very wrong, the game has been reset.");
            bank = 0;
        }


        System.out.println("Your number is: "+lotteryChance);
        System.out.println(win);    
    }   
    if(action == exit) {
        System.exit(1);
    }

    label.setText("<html><center><font color='white' size=5>Bank: $"+bank+"<br></font><font color='white'>Your number is: "+lotteryChance+"<br><br>"+win+"</font></center>    </html>");


}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TheLottery n = new TheLottery();
    n.TheLottery();

}
}
```

Comment: But you declare the bank to 0 every time you press a button. You need to increase the scope to an instance variable (move it outside the actionPerformed method), and it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the `bank` variable is the `actionPerformed` method. Every time you run this method it is set to `0`.

If you want the value to be kept between calls, make it a member variable like `frame` is.

BTW I suspect you don't need two JFrames.  Usually one is enough.

Comment: @ErikPragt perhaps it should have been an answer instead of a comment. ;)

Comment: Oh it's that simple, just put it in the class itself, not in any void! I was trying to leave it undefined in my void but then I got an error, so I tried to fixed it by putting 0 which is why I had this problem, but now it works. Thanks mate!